# Impossible to change the icon or splashscreen on iOS

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-ios

I simply can't replace the default logo (the white ".Net" on a purple background) with my own image. Whether it's the icon or the splashscreen, there's absolutely nothing I can do on iOS, I'm stuck.

What drives me crazy is that there's no trace of the original .svg files anymore, either in the solution or in the directories (the .bin and .obj directories have also been deleted countless times). I don't understand where it gets this ugly logo from.

(I should point this out, but like all the problems I've had so far with MAUI, everything works perfectly on Android or Windows, only iOS is a problem).

I've followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?tabs=ios

Note that I'm using .Net 8 (because .Net 7 also includes a large number of critical bugs on iOS).

So I have the following lines in my .csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.png" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splashscreen.png" />

    [...]
  </ItemGroup>
```

And I tried with and without these lines in Info.plist (taking care to uninstall the app and clean the directories between each attempt):

```
  <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
  <string>MauiSplash</string>
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried it with another PC, another project, in .net 7 (just in case it's a .net 8 problem), and I've got exactly the same behaviour; everything works fine on Android and Windows, I've got my icon and splashscreen, but on iOS I've still got that ".net" from hell coming out of nowhere.

Comment: You could try deleting the ForegroundFile attribute in MauiIcon item，and specifically you can refer to this document [Composed icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=macios#composed-icon).

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT Thx. But I'm beginning to know this document by heart, since I've been struggling with these icons for so long; none of the combinations work.
I challenge anyone to find me an sample that works (on iOS and with .net 8).

Comment: @JeremyA. I can successfully change the default splash screen on MAUI iOS, see [my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJB4g.png). Have you tried to use a svg file and change its name to a different one?